# The string erase() function is giving different results for similar calls

Tags: c++

I tried using the `string::erase()` function with 2 parameters for the start and the end point but it is giving me different results for the same type of call.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

   string s = "azxxzy";
   s.erase(2,2);
   cout << s;
   s.erase(1,1);
   cout << endl << s;
}
```

It deletes 2 characters i.e `xx` for the first call but for the second call it is deleting only one `z`.

Can you please explain why this is happening?

**CORRECTED**-

the question is wrong as I used the overloaded version i.e

'string& erase (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos); '

But expected the output from

'iterator erase(iterator first,iterator last)'

Comment: did you check what is the meaning of the parameters you are passing there? `2,2` can be considered "similar" to `1,1`, though it is quite different

Comment: When you passed `2` it deleted 2 characters and when you passed `1` it deleted 1 character. I sense a pattern.

Comment: So what output did you expect?

Comment: i expected the output to be 'ay'

Comment: Don't guess what stuff in C++ does, read up on what it does in the docs or in your C++ book. Guessing will get you nowhere.

Comment: And why do you expect `s.erase(1,1)` to erase 2 characters?

Comment: @tobi303 I thought if i pass erase(2,3) it would remove the 2nd and third character.

Comment: @zygoat read the answer below.

Comment: I edited the question. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 3):

You're using [std::string::erase()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) with the following synoptic:

> ```
> string& erase (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos);
> ```

It will erase the part of the string specified at the position `pos` with the length `len`. Note that the position index `pos` begins with 0. The default parameter for `len = npos` indicates all characters until the end.

In your example it means:

```
string s = "azxxzy";
s.erase(2,2);        /* azzy: deleting 2 characters from position 2 */
s.erase(1,1);        /* azy:  deleting 1 character from position 1  */
```

> In my textbook it was written that the 2 parameters of `std::string::erase` are `iterator first` and `iterator last`. That is why I assumed it was giving a strange result.

You mean the overloaded version:

```
iterator erase (iterator first, iterator last);
```

But you didn't provide an `iterator`. You're passing `int` literals that will be implicitly converted to `size_t`. In the link I've posted above you can see the overloaded version + example.

> I expected the output to be 'ay'

To get that output with `iterator`s do the following with [`std::string::begin()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/begin/) and [`std::string::end()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/end/):

```
string s = "azxxzy";
s.erase(s.begin() + 1, s.end() - 1); /* ay: deleting characters        */
                                     /* between 1st and last character */
```

Comment: In my textbook it was written that the 2 parameters of std::string::erase are iterator first and iterator last. That is why i assumed it was giving a strange result. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @zygoat: You mean the overloaded version: `iterator erase (iterator first, iterator last);`. But you didn't provide an iterator. You're passing `int` literals that will be implicitly converted to `size_t`. In the link I've posted in my answer you see the overloaded version + example.

Comment: @zygoat you are mentioning `iterator erase (iterator first, iterator last)` but you are using `string& erase (size_t position, size_t length);`

Comment: @zygoat imho this is something you should include in your question, because it explains your expectation, which atm arent clear from the question alone

Comment: Yup the book specified the overloaded version and I didn't see it. Sorry

Comment: Should I delete the question or keep it?

Comment: @zygoat: I think you can not delete this question as it got this up voted answer. You could accept this answer to you the community that this works for your qiestion.